# Bootstrap Carousel Example Not Displaying Text

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Hey guys I am working on messing with some boot strap feature and am having some issues with the carousel element.

I am trying to use this example -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/carousel/

and the issue that I am having is that my code has the carousel but the text above the blue button is not showing up... 
[What my page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X97w4.png)

Here is my code (just copied the example)
I think the issue must be with my css or bootstrap files

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--You do not see what is in the head-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
     <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/basic-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
     <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

        <!--Fav icon-->
        <link href="#" rel="favicon"/>  <!--Example link (images/favicon.png)-->

        <!--Title of page-->
        <title>Title - Home</title>
    </head>


<body>
    <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main role="main">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>


  <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

  <div class="container marketing">

    <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->


    <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It’ll blow your mind.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it’s that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

  </div><!-- /.container -->


  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer class="container">
    <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p>© 2017-2020 Company, Inc. · <a href="#">Privacy</a> · <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
  </footer>
</main>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/docs/4.5/assets/js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="/docs/4.5/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-1CmrxMRARb6aLqgBO7yyAxTOQE2AKb9GfXnEo760AUcUmFx3ibVJJAzGytlQcNXd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing carousel css in your code.

`<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/carousel/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">`

This help to set height of carousel item.

```
.carousel-item {
    height: 32rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--You do not see what is in the head-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/basic-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/carousel/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
     <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

        <!--Fav icon-->
        <link href="#" rel="favicon"/>  <!--Example link (images/favicon.png)-->

        <!--Title of page-->
        <title>Title - Home</title>
    </head>


<body>
    <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main role="main">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>


  <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

  <div class="container marketing">

    <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->


    <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It’ll blow your mind.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it’s that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

  </div><!-- /.container -->


  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer class="container">
    <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p>© 2017-2020 Company, Inc. · <a href="#">Privacy</a> · <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
  </footer>
</main>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/docs/4.5/assets/js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script><script src="/docs/4.5/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-1CmrxMRARb6aLqgBO7yyAxTOQE2AKb9GfXnEo760AUcUmFx3ibVJJAzGytlQcNXd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: This fixed the issue! Thank you!